# CSV Writer writing over itself

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am trying to create a CSV file with a list of URLs.

I am pretty new to programming, so please excuse any sloppy code.

I have a loop that runs through a list of places to get the list of URLs.

I then have a loop within that loop that exports the data to a CSV file.

```
import urllib, csv, re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
list_of_URLs = csv.reader(open("file_location_for_URLs_to_parse"))
for row in list_of_URLs:
    row_string = "".join(row)
    file = urllib.urlopen(row_string)
    page_HTML = file.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_HTML) # parsing HTML
    Thumbnail_image = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "remositorythumbnail"})
    Thumbnail_image_string = str(Thumbnail_image)
    soup_3 = BeautifulSoup(Thumbnail_image_string)
    Thumbnail_image_URL = soup_3.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")})
```

**This is the part that isn't working for me:**

```
    out  = csv.writer(open("file_location", "wb"), delimiter=";")
    for tag in soup_3.findAll('a', href=True):   
        out.writerow(tag['href'])
```

Basically the writer keeps on writing over itself, **is there a way to jump to below the first empty row on the CSV and start writing?**

Comment: since whitespaces are *extremely* important in Python, please reformat your code to something executable.

Comment: @Constantinius thanks, I have edited the code, let me know if that's what you meant, why are whitespaces so important in Python?

Comment: @Mark in case you are still wondering about whitespace here is a link - http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/block_indentation.hawk basically indentation indicates the beginning and end of functions and statements in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you closing the file after every write, or opening the file before every write? Just check that.
Also, try using "ab" mode instead of "wb". "ab" will append to the file.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that worked a treat, so simple I changed it to ab mode and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

Don't put this inside any loop:

```
out  = csv.writer(open("file_location", "wb"), delimiter=";")
```

Instead:

```
with open("file_location", "wb") as fout:
    out = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=";")
    # put for-loop here
```

Notes:

1. `open("file_location", "wb")` creates a new file, destroying any old file of the same name. This is why it
   looks like the writer is overwriting old lines.
2. Use [`with open(...) as ...`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) because it automatically closes the file
   for you when the `with-block` ends. This makes explicit when the file is closed. Otherwise, the file remains open (and maybe not completely flushed) until `out` is deleted or reassigned to a new value. It's not really your main problem here, but using `with` is too useful not to mention.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out, as I am just a beginner its fantastic to have experts giving great advice as it really speeds up the learning process, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The `open("file_location", "wb")` call, which you are doing once for every URL, is wiping out what you did to that file previously.  Move it outside your `for` loop so that it is only opened once for all the URLs.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question in such quick time, I solved the problem and learnt what not to do next time, thanks.